# cURL live output CLI

Tags: curl, output, command-line-interface

I try to have a "live output" of a web page in a shell script ; to explain, a little example :

With this "localhost/index.php" like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo 'Start<br />'.PHP_EOL;
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
    {
        echo '.';
        flush();ob_flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
echo PHP_EOL.'<br />End';
?>
```

I want to write a shell script which permit to have the "dots" on the screen that appears each second.

If I try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
curl 'localhost/index.php'
```

It shows the output only after each breaklines... Not after each update (or "echo" in PHP script)
If a pipe this, all output will be show at the end :/

Is there a way to have the real time output, like in a browser ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps curl's [-N / --no-buffer](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-N) option will help you?